# Issue in configuring nginx server-block with subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've always used apache for my own vps. Recently I've decided to switch over nginx. I've never used it before, so I'm figuring out some issues in configuring virtual host with subdomains.

My vps is running ubuntu 12.04, fresh install with no apache installed.

I want to store multiple website inside the folder /usr/share/nginx. Inside this dir I've the following structure:

```
root@mauro-vps:/usr/share/nginx# tree
.
├── blog.marano.tk
│   └── public_html
│       └── index.php
└── marano.tk
    └── public_html
        └── index.php
```

As you can see I've seted a free domain name (marano.tk) pointing to my vps's ip. And I want to store on this server two websites:

- blog.marano.tk
- marano.tk

Just to understand how nginx works.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the default one, I've edited nothing inside it.

Inside `/etc/nginx/sites-aviable` I've two configuration files (one for each domains):

- default (pointing to marano.tk)
- blog.marano.tk

First file  `#/etc/nginx/sites-aviable/default`

```
    server {

        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        root /usr/share/nginx/marano.tk/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name marano.tk www.marano.tk;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            # With php5-cgi alone
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm;
            #  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

Second files `/etc/nginx/sites-aviable/blog.marano.tk`

```
    server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6


        root /usr/share/nginx/blog.marano.tk/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name blog.marano.tk www.blog.marano.tk;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm;
    #  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
      } 
    }
```

Then I've symlinked both files:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-aviable/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-aviable/blog.marano.tk /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

After restarting nginx and php if I point to *blog.marano.tk* I still get the content inside **/usr/share/nginx/marano.tk/public_html/index.php** insted of **/usr/share/nginx/blog.marano.tk/public_html/index.php**

Where I'm going wrong?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Delete the `try_files` statement in the php location and try to put in this line `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Comment: In both the configuration files?

Comment: Yes. I believe the `try_files` doesn't need to be there since you pass the connection to the cgi server.

Comment: It's sites-available not sites-aviable which you have used throughout your code which would cause it to not work.